Splitting HTML into two parts
I am splitting an HTML text into two parts. When doing that breaking HTML can happen.
I had a fixing function that lookes like this:
$html_intro = '<h3>Title</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->substituteEntities = false;
$content = mb_convert_encoding($html_intro, 'html-entities', 'utf-8');
@$doc->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$html_intro = $doc->saveHTML();

Since i added the LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED parameters to not add body elements the repairing is no longer working.
This is what i get when doing var_dump($html_intro):
string(613) "<h3>Title<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></h3>"

You can see a simple example here: https://onlinephp.io/c/d4ba5
Why is the <h3> Tag getting broken like that?
It can be fixed by doing this again:
$html_intro = tidy_repair_string($html_intro, array('show-body-only' => true));

But that looks all very strange.

This is just my guess. Because the DOMDocument represents the whole document, it must have single root element. If there is no LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED flag it will fill in standard html structure where <html> is the required root element. But when the flag is present there is no <html> tag to be used as root element. Because of that it simply tries to "fix" the source by using the first encountered element (h3 in example) as root element.

@MichalHynčica That makes perfect sense. If I add <h1>Main Title</h1> in front then that gets used as the root and the <h3>Title</h3> remains intact.
